# Array-processing: Eigenstructure of the Spatial Covariance Matrix

Tags: math, signal-processing, linear-algebra

I've been staring at the following underlined statement from  [this book](https://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00118ED1V01Y200805ANT008) for hours, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how it can be right:
[image: ()]

For some definitions:
[image: ()] is an r x r matrix (we may ignore its contents for this purpose).

A is an N x r matrix defined as the following matrix of column vectors, where each vector is N elements long:

[image: ()]

First of all I'm convinced that when they write:

[image: ()]

they really mean:

[image: ()]

otherwise it simply would not make sense from the start. My confusion is when they say [image: ()] is a linear combination of the column vectors of A.
At first I thought maybe it just wasn't obvious to me, so I started doing the calculations as an exercise.

My calculation (please don't make me type all this into a text equation editor):

[image: notebook]

I THINK my calculation is correct, but there was a lot to keep track of, so...

I did not do the multiplication with [image: ()] because it's trivial, and it doesn't solve the problem.
How can the products of different elements (complex conjugated no less) of the vectors in A end up as a linear combination of the columns of A?

Am I forgetting something fundamental here? Maybe something to do with the fact that [image: ()] is an eigenvector of [image: ()]...?

Comment: Great question, good work on it, however it's off topic in this forum; you'll have to try math.stackexchange.com instead. My only advice at this point is to try to insert definitions of things (e.g. what does it mean to say q is an eigenvector of whatever matrix) and go from there; try to avoid writing out matrix products as summations -- that makes the algebra much more complex and (hopefully) is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a post on math.stackexchange here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102979/array-processing-eigenstructure-of-the-spatial-covariance-matrix